# RewriteRule - URL from Ugly to Pretty with variables not parsing correctly

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'd like some help rewriting an ugly url (http://example.com/image.php?id=1&name=Dog) to a pretty url (http://example.com/1/Dog) using Regex.

There are a lot of questions about the reverse version of this, and some other versions of the one I need. Nonetheless, they do not work.

```
RewriteRule ^image.php\?id=(.*)&name=(.*)$  http://example.com/$1/$2? [R=301,L]
```

This is the Regex I came up with. Testing it on Regex101 seems to be fine (?) https://regex101.com/r/uUlccx/2

It should be the reverse of this one:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /image.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

But it seems like it isn't. Anyone know how the RewriteRule should be?

Edit: http://htaccess.mwl.be?share=47b41b23-1752-5a26-8432-196c95d1d669 htaccess tester

Edit 2: I got a little bit further, but it still doesn't seem to be working completely. The second variable is not taken in to the rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&)?id=(.*)&name=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^image\.php$  http://example.com/%1/%2/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)&name=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^image\.php$  http://example.com/%1/%2/? [R=301,L]
```

This seems to be the solution. Query values cannot be found in the normal rewrite rule?